# Post mentioned user's avatar embedded using Discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm using Discord.js for a discord bot and I'm trying to make it so that when you do the command !avatar @user

It will reply back with an embedded image of the mentioned user's avatar. I keep getting:

```
(node:3168) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Invalid Form Body embed.image.url: Not a well formed URL.
```

This is the code I have so far, however I'm unaware of how else to grab the user's avatar?

```
    const Discord = require('discord.js');
const config = require('./config.json');
const client = new Discord.Client();

function getUserFromMention(mention) {
    if (!mention) return;
    if (mention.startsWith('<@') && mention.endsWith('>')) {
        mention = mention.slice(2, -1);
        if (mention.startsWith('!')) {
            mention = mention.slice(1);
        }
        return client.users.get(mention);
    }
}

function getUserFromMentionRegEx(mention) {
    const matches = mention.match(/^<@!?(\d+)>$/);  
    const id = matches[1];
    return client.users.get(id);
}

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ready!');
});

const prefix = "!";
client.on('message', message => {
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;  
    const withoutPrefix = message.content.slice(prefix.length);
    const split = withoutPrefix.split(/ +/);
    const command = split[0];
    const args = split.slice(1);

    if (command === 'avatar') {
        if (args[0]) {          
            const user = getUserFromMention(args[0]);
            const userAvatar = user.displayAvatarURL;
            if (!user) {
                return message.reply('Please use a proper mention if you want to see someone else\'s avatar.');
            }
            const avatarEmbed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
            .setColor('#275BF0')
            .setImage('userAvatar');
            message.channel.send(avatarEmbed);
        }

        return message.channel.send(`${message.author.username}, your avatar: ${message.author.displayAvatarURL}`);
    }
});

client.login(config.token);
```

Answer (score 0):

you dont need parse mentions with another function, discord have method for this. You can use `message.mentions.members.first()`

And you try to set image a string, with text `userAvatar` so sure you got error.

You can get mention member avatar and send it with this code.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const config = require('./config.json');
const client = new Discord.Client();


client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ready!');
});

const prefix = "!";

client.on('message', message => {
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;  
    const withoutPrefix = message.content.slice(prefix.length);
    const split = withoutPrefix.split(/ +/);
    const command = split[0];
    const args = split.slice(1);    



    if (command === 'avatar') {
        let targetMember;
        if(!message.mentions.members.first()) {
            targetMember = message.guild.members.get(message.author.id);
        } else {
            targetMember = message.mentions.members.first()
        }

        let avatarEmbed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
            .setImage(targetMember.user.displayAvatarURL)
            .setColor(targetMember.displayHexColor);
            message.channel.send(avatarEmbed);
    }
});
```